# Clear Azure App service PHP cache

Tags: php, azure, caching

I am modifying a PHP file stored on the Azure App service. While I am editing the file, my Azure site continues to use a cached version of the file. Until now, the only way I can see changes is to restart App service.

Is there any way to delete a file from the cache or delete the whole cache?

Answer (score 2):

I asked MSFT support. This solve cache problems:
Go to `Application settings`, scroll to `App settings` and add following:
Key: `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE`
Value: `0`

Answer (score 0):

There is a `response buffer` settings on IIS by default. We can leverage the hint of [How to: Use a custom PHP runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-use-a-custom-php-runtime) to modify the setting in `web.config` in your root directory of your application.

We can use the Azure build-in PHP runtime instead our custom PHP runtime mentioned above, consider the following content in `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
      <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
            <add name="PHP-FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe"
               resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
         </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I do not need to change PHP runtime. I added my PHP file to D:\home\site\wwwroot sub folder. To avoid caching I created web.config in this folder:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <caching enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>` .   It doesn't help.

Comment: Dose the configuration work for you? On my side, I only can disable the cache mechanism by IIS via using custom PHP runtime as a workaround.